# Python: remove() doesn't seems to work

Tags: python

I searched for a while but I can't find a solution to my problem. I'm still new to Python, so I'm sometime struggling with obvious things... Thanks by advance for your advises!

I have a list containing objects and duplicates of these objects, both have specific names: `objects_ext` and `duplicatedObject_SREF_ext`. What I want is that if there is a duplicated object in my list, check if the original object is also in list, if it is, remove the duplicated object from list.

I tried to use the `remove()` method, as there can only be one occurrence of each name in the list, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
rawSelection = [u'crapacruk_high', u'doubidou_high', u'blahbli_high', u'crapacruk_SREF_high', u'doubidou_SREF_high', u'blahbli_SREF_high']
# objects with '_SREF_' in their names are the duplicated ones
for obj in rawSelection:
    if '_SREF_' in str(obj):
        rawName = str(obj).split('_')
        rootName = rawName [0]
        defName = rootName + '_' + '_'.join(rawName[2:])
        if defName in rawSelection:
            rawSelection.remove (obj)
# Always returns:
# [u'crapacruk_high', u'doubidou_high', u'blahbli_high', u'doubidou_SREF_high']
# Instead of:
# [u'crapacruk_high', u'doubidou_high', u'blahbli_high']
```

**Edit:** Oh, forgot to say that the duplicated object must be removed from list only if the original one is in it too.

Comment: Don't iterate over a list while you modify it. That's not ever going to work.

Comment: You'd be much better off just creating a `set` object from your `list` object. It will remove the duplicates: `newobj = set(mylist)` EDIT: nevermind. Didn't realize the strings aren't identical.

Comment: @Morgan Thrapp Do you have an alternative? Maybe with a generator? Thanks

Comment: Does `u'doubidou_high'` always appear first, before the `'_SREF_'` version?

Comment: @UKDP Create a new list?

Comment: @Rick Teachey, I'm afraid no, it depends on the user's selection...

Comment: @UKDP Edited my answer: turns out that with my method the order doesn't matter. I was mistaken.

Comment: @UKDP - do you need to maintain the original order aside from removing dupes?

Comment: `rawSelection = [x for x in rawSelection if '_SREF' not in x or x.replace('_SREF', '') not in rawSelection]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski This comment is very obviously the best answer. Keeps the order and everything. Excellent work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the for loop from `for obj in rawSelection:` to `for obj in list(rawSelection):`. This should fix your issue as it iterates over the copy of the list. The way you do it, you modify the list while iterating over it, leading to problems.

```
rawSelection = [u'crapacruk_high', u'doubidou_high', u'blahbli_high', u'crapacruk_SREF_high', u'doubidou_SREF_high', u'blahbli_SREF_high']

for obj in list(rawSelection):
    if '_SREF_' in str(obj):
        rawName = str(obj).split('_')
        rootName = rawName [0]
        defName = rootName + '_' + '_'.join(rawName[2:])
        if defName in rawSelection:
            rawSelection.remove (obj)

print(rawSelection)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're mutating the same list you're iterating over.

When you remove `u'crapacruk_SREF_high'` from the list, everything after it shifts to the left (this done on the C source code level) so the value of `obj` is now `u'doubidou_SREF_high'`.  Then the end of the for loop comes and `obj` becomes the next element in the list, `u'blahbli_SREF_high'`.

To fix this you can copy the list over and get

```
for obj in rawSelection[:]:
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want (note that it doesn't matter what order the items appear in):

```
rawSelection = list({i.replace('_SREF', '') for i in rawSelection})
```

This works by iterating through the original list, and removing the `'_SREF'` substring from each item. Then each edited string object is added to a `set` comprehension (that's what the `{}` brackets mean: a new `set` object is being created). Then the `set` object is turned back into a `list` object.

This works because for `set` objects, you can't have duplicate items, so when an attempt is made to add a duplicate, it fails (silently). Note that the order of the original items is not preserved.

EDIT: as @PeterDeGlopper pointed out in the comments, this does not work for the constraint that the `_SREF_` item only gets removed only if the original appears. For that, we'll do the following:

```
no_SREF_Set = {i for i in rawSelection if '_SREF_' not in i}
rawSelection = list({i.replace('_SREF', '') if i.replace('_SREF', '') in no_SREF_Set else i for i in rawSelection})
```

You can combine this into a one-liner, but it's a little long for my taste:

```
rawSelection = list({i.replace('_SREF', '') if i.replace('_SREF', '') in {i for i in rawSelection if '_SREF_' not in i} else i for i in rawSelection})
```

This works by creating a `set` of the items that don't have `'_SREF_'`, and then creating a new `list` (similar to the above) that only replaces the `'_SREF'` if the no `'_SREF_'` version of the item appears in the `no_SREF_Set`.

Comment: Actually, no, this fails the constraint that "the duplicated object must be removed from list only if the original one is in it too".

Comment: I'm also not sure it's established yet that the order doesn't have to be preserved. The OP has said that it's not necessarily the case that the duplicate version comes after the original version, but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Edited the answer to fix the problem you pointed out in the first comment. It's true that the order isn't preserved, though.

Comment: @Stuart Working now. Copied it over from the console earlier incorrectly.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper The edit I made earlier had a bug. Now it's right.

Comment: You're closer, IMO, but `rawSelection = [i for i in rawSelection if '_SREF' not in i or i.replace('_SREF', '') not in no_SREF_Set]` would preserve order with very little if any extra time required.  Assuming the lists are long enough for peformance to matter, anyway - if not, @StevenRumbalski's list comprehension wins for correctness and readability.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper yeah I totally agree his comment is definitely the best way as long as the lists aren't too long. But at least I got mine working. haha.

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem up into subtasks

```
def get_orig_name(name):
    if '_SREF_' in name:
        return '_'.join(name.split('_SREF_'))
    else:
        return name
```

Then just construct a new list with no dups

```
rawSelection = [u'crapacruk_high', 
                u'doubidou_high', 
                u'blahbli_high', 
                u'crapacruk_SREF_high', 
                u'doubidou_SREF_high', 
                u'blahbli_SREF_high']

uniqueList = [ n for n in rawSelection if ('_SREF_' not in n) or    
                                          (get_orig_name(n) not in rawSelection ) ]

print uniqueList
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` to get quite a clean solution.

```
def non_duplicate(s):
    return not('_SREF_' in s and s.replace('_SREF', '') in raw_selection)

filtered_selection = filter(non_duplicate, raw_selection)
```